# Column value divided by row count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What happens when each column value in a table is divided with the total table row count. What function is basically performed by sql server? Can any one help?

More specifically: what is the difference between `sum(column value ) / row count` and `column value/ row count`. for e.g,

```
select cast(officetotal as float) /count(officeid) as value, 
sum(officetotal)/ count(officeid) as average from check1 
where officeid ='50009' group by officeid,officetotal
```

What is the operation performed on both select?

Comment: Which function? Hmmm... division.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but what is the difference between  sum(column value ) / row count   and  column value/ row count .            
 for e.g,  
             
 select cast(officetotal as float) /count(officeid) as value , sum(officetotal)/ count(officeid) as average 
from check1 where officeid ='50009' group by officeid,officetotal.   

what operation performs on both select?

Comment: In first example you are deviding sum of values on count of rows. In second you are deviding value on count of rows. Why it is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example both will be allways the same value because `count(officeid)` is allways equal to 1 because officeid is contained in the WHERE clause and officetotal is also contained in GROUP BY clause. So the example will not work because no grouping will be applied.

When you remove `officetotal` from the GROUP BY, you will get following message:

> Column 'officetotal' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

It means that you cannot use `officetotal` and `SUM(officetotal)` in one select - because SUM is meant to work for set of values and it is pointless to SUM only one value.

It is just not possible to write it this way in SQL using GROUP BY. If you look for something like first or last value from a group, you will have to use `MIN(officetotal)` or `MAX(officetotal)` or some other approach.

Comment: He _could_ use `officetotal / sum(officetotal) over ()`

Comment: thanks for your answers. But one thing is still unclear to me .   dividing value on count of rows. what does it returns? .what sql server wiil do in this case? . ( i knew  dividing sum of a value on count of rows returns average of that particular value.)

Comment: In that SP, they are taking average of client per office  (for eg: for office id 50009 it is 359).  then they divide that average with (359) total count of 50009 office id (252). so 352/252 = 1.4.  what will be the result set to be called? (it is basically value of each row / table count). what operation sql server perform by dividing average by count. is it average of average?

Comment: Hard to say without the original query and without knowing the purpose of the query and without knowing the data... You can create SQL Fiddle if you wish to learn more http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a19a/3